# Why is apt checking for updates every 10 minutes?

Tags: apt, updates

I have four VMs that are all having CPU usage spikes every 10 minutes. These spikes coincide perfectly with DNS lookups for hostnames including `archive.canonical.com` and `security.ubunutu.com` (per tcpdump), so I assume apt is checking for updates. It's configured to check for updates daily. I can't figure out what's causing this 10-minute interval.

I've looked in `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/`, `/var/log/dpkg.log`, `/var/log/apt` and journalctl and can't find anything corresponding to a 10-minute interval.

These VMs are stock Google Cloud Ubuntu 19.10 images with very few changes (MongoDB installed [which added repo.mongodb.org as an apt source], logging and monitoring agents installed, THP disabled).

What should I do/where should I look to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Start with `ls -l /var/lib/apt/periodic`. That will tell you the last time unattended-upgrades ran. Next, try `systemctl list-timers apt-daily.timer apt-daily-upgrade.timer` for the next time apt will update/upgrade automatically.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks. `/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp`'s timestamp coincides with the 10-min interval. `unattended-upgrades-stamp` and all others are much older. Those two systemd timers have intervals of 6h and 24h. None of the other systemd timers have short intervals either. -- So the question remains, why is apt updating ever 10 mins...

Comment: Oddly ... there's an entry in `/var/log/apt/history.log` from yesterday for `Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get remove -y unattended-upgrades`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urg, this is the [Google osconfig-agent](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os). Apparently it polls every 10 minutes *and* disables automatic apt updates (re: my comment about the surprising `apt-get remove -y unattended-upgrades` line in the apt history).